# Code for watched computed property never seems to run

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I'm watching a computed property returning a state variable.

I know for sure that this state variable changes as a result of certain things I do. Yet the `console.log()` code in my `watch: {}` never executes:

```
computed: {
  simulation () {
    return this.$store.state.simulation
  }
},
watch: {
  simulation () {
    console.log('simulation changed:')
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a sanity check: Do you see the change happening in Vue Devtools?

Comment: Yes sir, I just did. Note that `simulation` is an object, and the property of this object that changed is itself an array of objects. Not sure if that matters but just in case.

Comment: It certainly does. Have a look at this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: You might try changing your watch to watch the specific property of the simulation that is changing

Comment: Looks like I learned something new, thanks! Well the change is addition of new items to the array which is a property of `simulation`. I guess I'll use something else altogether. If you want you can make an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: can't you add `,deep: true` after `simulation(){...}` and it will notify you of change?

Comment: I can't try right now but if you're sure this option will detect the addition of new items inside an array which is a property of the object I want to watch then please make an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `this.$store.state.simulation` is object, you can't watch for change property of object. You can watch change of object (when `this.$store.state.simulation = newVal`, but not `this.$store.state.simulation.anyProp = newVal`)
you should use deep watch (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

Answer (score 0):

Through our conversation in the comments of the original post, we found that a property of `simulation` was being changed, rather than the entire `simulation` object. To detect such changes, OP simply needs to `watch` the specific property of `simulation` that is being changed, rather than the whole `simulation` object.

Comment: or use the deep option in the watcher if he wish to catch all props's changes.